# Over-plot an equation curve over a png image

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5l5w.png)I'm having trouble overplotting a relation between radial velocity and offset(position). I've looked at various solutions, but it doesn't seem to work. I've converted the equation into numbers, with only one variable.It also doesn't display the picture to the required dimensions.

```
x = np.linspace(-0.8 ,0.8 , 1000)  

y = 0.5*((1.334e+20/x)**0.5)

img = plt.imread('Pictures/PVdiagram1casaviewer.png')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 16), tight_layout=True)

ax.set_xlabel('Offset(arcsec)', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('Radial Velocity (Km/S)', fontsize=14)

ax.imshow(img, extent=[-0.8, 0.8, -5, 15])
ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=5, color='white')


plt.title('PV Diagram')

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNMw8.png)

Comment: Probably your `image`-axis is different from the `plot`-axis (which includes very huge values and `nan` values by the way). Try comment `ax.imshow(img, extent=[-0.8, 0.8, -5, 15])` out and look at the plot /axisvalues and the same with commenting out `ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=5, color='white')`.

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't display the picture, and my required axes dimensions are not satisfied.

Comment: Could you share your image?

Comment: I've added the picture and the  plot I need to overplot to the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I plot your image, you can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqJNv.png) that the axis of the image and `matplotlib` don't match, because the image contains space between the plot and border of the pictures (axis titles, and so on...)

So, first you need to crop the image, so that it contains just the [plot area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnQVl.png).

Next, you can plot the image with the argument `aspect=auto` to scale it to your figsize:

```
ax.imshow(img, extent=[-0.8,0.8,-5,15], aspect='auto')
```

[image]

If you try to plot your `y` function over the image, you will see that the values of `y` are much larger, so the curve is [above the image (notice the tiny image is at the bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzuDy.png).

I don't know what the *physical* background of `y` is, but if you divide it by `10e9` it fits inside the image-range.

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-0.8 ,0.8 , 1000)  

y = 0.5*((1.334e+20/x)**0.5)/10e9 # Scale it here... but how?

img = plt.imread('hNMw82.png')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 16), tight_layout=True)

ax.set_xlabel('Offset(arcsec)', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('Radial Velocity (Km/S)', fontsize=14)

ax.imshow(img, extent=[-0.8,0.8,-5,15], aspect='auto')
ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=5, color='white')
ax.set_ylim([-5,15])
ax.set_xlim([-0.8,0.8])

plt.title('PV Diagram')

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

(I also set the axis limits.)

Comment: Thank you so much! My error was that I hadn't converted my units while doing the math. But you also helped me out with the scaling issue, so I appreciate it :)

Comment: Happy to help! :-)